# Is it possible to filter on a list of pairs in Solr?

Tags: search, solr

Is it possible to filter on a list of pairs in Solr? For instance, if I was filter products and I wanted to select all products except

```
[COLOR] [TYPE]
Blue    Mugs
Red     Shirts
Green   Pants
```

How would I write that query? Everything I have read is based on filtering disjointed lists i.e. -color:(Blue Red Green) -type:(Mugs Shirts Pants)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the exact structure of your documents - as long as these are single valued fields (meaning that they do not contain several entries for each document), filtering them should be doable by:

```
-((color:Blue AND type:Mugs) OR (color:Red AND type:Shirts) ..)
```